# How to get different blocks from the borders in image using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, contour

I am using OpenCV with C++.

I have the following image ->

[image]

I want to replicate the cell structure in this image into an excel sheet.I have managed to OCR the texts but not getting exactly how we can replicate the structure to excel.
I was thinking of cropping out the blocks and so I tried few techniques like using `HoughLinesP()` for seperating each cell but its just not working and also tried line pattern matching with `minMaxLoc()` but that's also not giving a good result.

Is there any reliable technique to do this in OpenCV ?

Comment: `findContours()` may help in this case

Comment: @ZdaR o I will try and see !

Comment: Start by taking a better picture?!